# How can I find strings that are not in a text file?

Tags: powershell

I have a list of strings called $tokens.
I have a blob of text called $textblob.

I need to find all the $tokens that are *not* found anywhere in $textblob.

I can get close, but I can't wrap my head around the syntax (I'm still pretty new to Powershell). I think it would look something like this:

$tokens | Where-Object $textblob -NotMatch $_

But, of course, that doesn't work. The first parameter to Where-Object needs to be $_.

Comment: Could you update this an add some examples of the first few lines each of `$tokens` and `$textBlob`?  Please be sure to remove and PII or Company related info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a scriptblock with `Where-Object`, this way you can pass `$_` as whichever operand you need to:

```
$tokens | Where-Object { $textblob -notmatch [regex]::Escape($_) }
```